# Convert jquery to javascript to help display a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to toggle a checkbox so that is it will display a header/div that is currently

```
@media screen and (max-width: 639.98px){
    #menuPanel{
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

I'm getting unresolved method on `ready` in the JQuery so I must be using the library wrong.

I'm new to JQuery and Javascript and was wondering is there a way to convert this Jquery to javascript?

```
(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myCheck').change(function() {
       $('#menuPanel').toggle();
  });
 });
```

With some html

```
<div class="hamburger">
            <label class="toggle" id="menuDisplay">
                <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck">
```

```
 <header class="masthead mb-auto" id="menuPanel">
```

Current code in this js file is working.

```
function displayWindowSize() {
    var w = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    var toggle = document.querySelector(".toggle input");

    if (w > 640) {
        toggle.checked = false;
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: For me it is not clear, what you really want. Do you want a Jquery solution or an plain vanilla javascript solution?

Comment: `(document).ready` should probably be `$(document).ready`

Comment: @ChristianMüller sorry I know. i kind of am wondering why my solution isnt working in jquery and also how the working jquery would be in javascript at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, that `jQuery` ' script ' will not work because you should have `$(document).ready(function(){ })`

Second, you do not need to load `jQuery` to achieve what you want.

You can apply an `onclick` event on the checkbox, then check if it is checked or not and show/hide your menu.

```js
var menu = document.getElementById('menuPanel');
function checkboxChanged(event) {
  event.target.checked ? menu.style.display = 'block' :  menu.style.display = 'none'
}
```

```css
#menuPanel {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<header class="masthead mb-auto" id="menuPanel">HEADER</header>

<div class="hamburger">
  <label class="toggle" id="menuDisplay">
    <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="checkboxChanged(event)" />
  </label>
</div>
```

OR if you cannot change HTML and apply a function inline, you can do everything inside the `script` tags

```js
var menu = document.getElementById('menuPanel');
var checkbox = document.getElementById('myCheck');
checkbox.onclick = function() {
  this.checked ? 
     menu.style.cssText += ';display:block !important;': menu.style.cssText += ';display:none !important;'
}
```

```css
#menuPanel {
  display: none!important;
}
```

```html
<header class="masthead mb-auto" id="menuPanel">HEADER</header>

<div class="hamburger">
  <label class="toggle" id="menuDisplay">
    <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" />
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: @Joelad I must insist that you avoid using `!important` css rules. But, if you reeeeeally have to, you can overwrite them in a few ways. Check the second snippet in the answer. Using `element.style.cssText += ';display:block !important;'` . I used `+=` so you append a style to the existing styles of the element ( header in your case ) and not replace them. EDIT : This comment was added because the OP commented ( then deleted it ) that he has to overwrite the `!important` style from `@media query`

Comment: Sorry deleted my comment above by accident.

Comment: @Joelad No worries. Does this solve your problem ? ( check the second snippet in the answer )

Comment: But I'll try to avoid it. Ill give that second js a go thank you!

Comment: @Joelad No problem. Glad i could help. Cheers ! :D . As a conclusion : Avoid jQuery ( only if you really need some external libraries and plugins that are based on jQuery ) . You can do everything in plain javaScript. And avoid using `!important` . Try using CSS specificity to achieve what you want.

Comment: it definetly is the answer but on testing I have a couple slight issues. Being my code as opposed to yours. Its to do with menu being displayed when i want and not when i want it to. Its all coming down to the toggle of the checkbox and switching between screen sizes. I probably need to integrate the display block and none with the width

Comment: @Joelad `menu being displayed when i want and not when i want it to.` what do you mean ? you mean that under `639.98px` the menu should be hidden even if the checkbox is  checked ?

Comment: The menu in larger screen is fine when checkbox is left on true or not touched when on the smaller screen. But if its left on true and i go back to the smaller screen, the menu is still displayed and the checkbox is set back to false. Then clicking of the checkbox again does nothing until checkbox is returned back to false and it repeats (if you know what i mean) :/ But I want menu hidden and checkbox to be false when i go back to the smaller screen

Comment: well that happens because maybe you have another javascript code that turns the `checked` state to false below `640px`. I suggest you post another question with this new problem. Try inserting a code snippet in that question that reproduces your problem. Include the code you have from this answer too.

Comment: Sounds like it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you want to use the jQuery version of `document.ready`. For that you have to prepend a `$` symbol, like so:

```
$(document).ready( ... )
```

Comment: This is correct, however the question is asking to translate the jQuery to plain JS

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I would like it in javascript as looks nice and consistent but probably knowing why ready() isnt working for jquery is helpful too :)